# How to change binary value to an array with individual states

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary

I have a question. How can I import value like this:

```
value = 0b1010
```

to an array like this:

```
array = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0])
```

and vice versa?

Comment: You can use `unpackbits`, or shift if you want less digits: `(value & 1 << np.arange(4) > 0).view('i1')`.  To use `unpackbits` you will have to cast first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.binary_repr` function turn integers into binary representation string, so you could do:

```
import numpy as np
value = 0b1010
arr = np.array(list(np.binary_repr(value)),dtype=int)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[1 0 1 0]
```

Reverse direction (as requested by @sai):

```
arr = np.array([1,0,1,0],dtype=int)
value = np.sum(arr * [2**i for i in reversed(range(len(arr)))])
print(value)
```

Output:

```
10
```

Explanation: I build `list` with desceding powers of `2` (in this case [8,4,2,1]) using `list` comprehension then multiply `arr` (i.e. multiply pairwise elements from `arr` and said `list`) then `np.sum`.

Comment: you might wanna add the second part for converting array to a binary value, as OP is looking for both the methods i.e. "vice versa"

Answer (score 0):

One solution which does not require invoking numpy or any other special packages is to shift each bit and calculate the remainder.

```
>>> val = 0b1010101
>>> arr = [(val>>i)%2 for i in reversed(range(val.bit_length()))]
>>> print(arr)
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

One possibility to go the other direction is through a concatenated string which gets converted to an integer:

```
>>> val_2 = int(''.join((str(x) for x in arr)), 2)
>>> print(val == val_2)
True
```